# Missing Published Classes on Service Reference C#

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, wsdl

First time here, never had the need to ask for anything due it was always easy to find the answer in other questions made.

The problem i'm facing:

I've just added the ServiceLayer which is going to publish services correspondant to BusinesLogicLayer.

So this is my code:

```
using Shared.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; 
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ServiceLayer
{
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceEmployees
{
    [OperationContract]
    void AddEmployee(Employee emp);

    [OperationContract]
    void DeleteEmployee(int id);

    [OperationContract]
    void UpdateEmployee(Employee emp);

    [OperationContract]
    List<Employee> GetAllEmployees();

    [OperationContract]
    Employee GetEmployee(int id);

    [OperationContract]
    double CalcPartTimeEmployeeSalary(int idEmployee, int hours);
}
}
```

Next file:

```
using BusinessLogicLayer;
using Shared.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ServiceLayer
{
public class ServiceEmployees : IServiceEmployees
{
    private static IBLEmployees blHandler;

    public ServiceEmployees()
    {
        blHandler = Program.blHandler;
    }

    public void AddEmployee(Employee emp)
    {
        blHandler.AddEmployee(emp);
    }

    public void DeleteEmployee(int id)
    {
        blHandler.DeleteEmployee(id);
    }

    public void UpdateEmployee(Employee emp)
    {
        blHandler.UpdateEmployee(emp);
    }

    public List<Employee> GetAllEmployees()
    {
        return blHandler.GetAllEmployees();
    }

    public Employee GetEmployee(int id)
    {
        return blHandler.GetEmployee(id);
    }

    public double CalcPartTimeEmployeeSalary(int idEmployee, int hours)
    {
        return blHandler.CalcPartTimeEmployeeSalary(idEmployee, hours);
    }
    }
    }
```

Next file:

```
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Text;
     using System.Threading.Tasks;
     using System.Runtime.Serialization;

     namespace Shared.Entities
     {

     [DataContract]
     [KnownType(typeof(FullTimeEmployee))]
     [KnownType(typeof(PartTimeEmployee))]
     public abstract class Employee
     {
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    }
    }
```

Next Files:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using System.Runtime.Serialization;

  namespace Shared.Entities
  {
[DataContract]
public class FullTimeEmployee : Employee
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}
}
```

Last File:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    namespace Shared.Entities
    {
    [DataContract]
    public class PartTimeEmployee : Employee
    {
    [DataMember]
    public double HourlyRate { get; set; }
    }
    }
```

Allright, those are the ones i need to get published in a wsdl to consume later instead of accessing in PresentationLayer to BusinessLayer and DataLayer.

I've managed to get the published those OperationContracts without problems, and
when i add the url as an service reference on the PresentationLayerWinForm , i get the following.

[wsdl description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl5ve.png)

I need to see the Employee.cs, PartTimeEmployee, FullTimeEmployee clases as well in that description but i dont get them although they are defined in the wsdl.

[wsdl_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEhdL.png)

What could possibly went wrong ?

Ive cleaned my proyect, rebuiled it several times and i still get the same thing, and i need those clases te get published so i errase the reference to shared.entities from PresentationLayerWinForm

Thanks 4 helping,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved;

The issue was that my  server-side DataContract class is named the same as a class i'm using local to the client of the web service, so  Visual Studio re-uses types by default. Right-click on the Service Reference, Click on Configure and turn off Type re-use.

Thanks Anyway.